# How to find and replace extra new lines in java?

Tags: java, string, special-characters, find-replace

I am trying to remove extra new lines using the following code snippet:

```
    while(true){
        line = line.replaceAll("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n").replaceAll("\n\n", "\n").replaceAll("\r\r", "\r");
        if ((line.indexOf("\r\n\r\n") < 0) && (line.indexOf("\n\n") < 0) && (line.indexOf("\r\r") < 0)){
            break;
        }
    };
```

but it doesn't remove extra new lines. Please help me.

Input:

```
Print





ID: 12345678


TimeStamp: 05/17/2019 3:00:35 pm




Status: Open
```

Expected Output:

```
Print
ID: 12345678
TimeStamp: 05/17/2019 3:00:35 pm
Status: Open
```

Comment: Give an example please!

Comment: Added input and expected output!

Comment: If variable 'line' is in fact a single line, as its name strongly suggests, there are not going to be extra newlines in it; a 'line' ends at the first \n characer.  How is 'line' set up?

Answer (score 0):

Replace multiple line breaks with one line break,

```
line.trim().replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", "\n")
```